# Euler Angle to Quaternion Conversion in Java

Tags: java, quaternions, euler-angles

This is something what probably was asked before,
but I could not find a working answer.

I am trying to convert Euler angles into a quaternion
(easier and faster calucations, no gimbel lock),
but for some reason it does not work.
I am using a tinkerforge IMUV2,
which does (amoung others) deliver me with the attitude quaternion,
attitude Euler angles and attitude change in Euler angle.

I am using the quaternion and the Euler angle attitude to determine if my transformation from Euler angles to quaternions is correct.
Strangely, so far, only the scalar part I calculate is correct;
the vector part is utter nonsense.
I am simply unable to find my mistake.

The Formula is

```
q=[cos(w/2),v_x sin(w/2),v_y sin(w/2),v_z sin(w/2)]
```

w is the vector angle ||v||; and v the normalized vector v/||v||.

```
    public static Quaternion eulerToQuaternion(short[] eulerR,double dt){

    double[] euler = new double[] {eulerR[0]/16*(Math.PI/180),eulerR[1]/16*(Math.PI/180),eulerR[2]/16*(Math.PI/180)};

    double scalar = Math.sqrt(euler[0]*euler[0]+euler[1]*euler[1]+euler[2]*euler[2]);
    double[] vector = new double[]{euler[0]/scalar,euler[1]/scalar,euler[2]/scalar};
    scalar = scalar*dt;
    double a = Math.sin(scalar/2);
    return new Quaternion(Math.cos(scalar/2),vector[0]*a,vector[1]*a,vector[2]*a);

}
```

I convert the input with `1/16*(Math.PI/180)` because the tinkerforge output is in 1/16° and i need it in radians.
I would be really surprised if that is the issue.
The dt part is for the future and i keep dt=1.
The constructor simply arranges the values in an array for a Quaternion class I wrote to make calculations.

The approach from wikipedia does not work either (scalar and vector part are both wrong).

Edit: Balazs Vago spotted the mistake of me using the first euler angle three times.
With switched the second and third value of the resulting quaternion and taking the congruent I was able to make the wikipedia version work (edited version)

```
    public static Quaternion toQuaternion(short[] euler, double dt)
{
    double yaw=euler[0]/16*(Math.PI/180);
    double roll=euler[1]/16*(Math.PI/180);
    double pitch=euler[2]/16*(Math.PI/180);
    double t0 = Math.cos(yaw * 0.5);
    double t1 = Math.sin(yaw * 0.5);
    double t2 = Math.cos(roll * 0.5);
    double t3 = Math.sin(roll * 0.5);
    double t4 = Math.cos(pitch * 0.5);
    double t5 = Math.sin(pitch * 0.5);

    return new Quaternion(t0 * t2 * t5 + t1 * t3 * t4,-(t0 * t2 * t4 + t1 * t3 * t5),-(t0 * t3 * t4 - t1 * t2 * t5),-(t1 * t2 * t4 - t0 * t3 * t5));
}
```

This version is somewhat inefficient and I still need help with `eulerToQuaternion` to understand my mistake.

Comment: Might not be relevant, but in function `toQuaternion` you use the first array element 3 times.

Comment: i did not want to use toQuaternion and did not pay it mutch attention. But yes, fixing that and for some reason switching the secound and third value of the result i get the kongruent of the wanted Quaternion. Thank your for sharp eyes and common sense ;)

Comment: Well you could store a "constant" with pi/180, and also divide by 32, so you don't have to "multiply" by 0.5.